# HttpRequest как получить данные

Tags: php

У меня есть HttpRequest, который шлет данные методом POST. Я не могу получить их. 
Пыталась вот так:

```
$n = $_POST;
```

Думала, что таким способом я смогу получить все, что отправляю методом POST, но, видимо, нет, не получилось.

Comment: Как именно вы отправляете запрос?

Comment: Ну и конкретика по отправляемым данным тоже не помешала бы

Comment: Запрос происходит на другом языке. Он рабочий. Проверен был тестовым http://posttestserver.com, отобразилось все то, что было отправлено. Как они там реализовали прием данных - не знаю.

Comment: Без конкретики по запросу это все гадание на кофейной гуще. Может быть вы не туда отправляете запрос. А может быть не правильно используете полученные данные. А может быть в вашем PHP скрипте есть ошибка. А может быть файервол на сервере не позволяет принимать запросы... я могу продолжать "телепатить" очень долго, но принцип вы, наверное, поняли

Comment: поменяйте свой оператор на `var_dump($_POST);` посмотрите, что там есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_POST - это массив, что бы достать оттуда значение обращаться нужно так: $_POST['**Имя**'], то что жирненькое замените на ваше значение.